# Guest share for domain-integrated Samba-Server

Tags: domain, samba, network-share, share, guest

Have set up a Windows-domain-integrated samba server. Sharing files is working pretty well but failing to set up a guest share as long the `security` is set to `ads`. This is a shortened version of the configuration containing a share free to a certain domain group and a non working share for non authenticated users. I've attached the smb.conf for reference.

```
[global]
    workgroup = MYDOMAIN
    dns proxy = no
    netbios name = myshare
    clustering = yes

    security = ads
    realm = mydomain.com
    password server = 1.2.3.4
    winbind enum users = yes
    winbind enum groups = yes
    winbind cache time = 10
    winbind use default domain = yes
    client use spnego = yes
    client ntlmv2 auth = yes
    encrypt passwords = yes
    restrict anonymous = 2
    domain master = no
    local master = no
    preferred master = no
    os level = 0
    idmap uid = 100000-109999
    idmap gid = 100000-109999

    log file = /var/log/samba/log
    log level = 3
    max log size = 1000
    syslog = 0
    panic action = /usr/share/samba/panic-action %d

    server role = standalone server
    passdb backend = tdbsam

    unix password sync = yes
    pam password change = yes
    map to guest = bad user
    guest account = nobody


[public]
    browsable = yes
    create mask = 0666
    directory mask = 0777
    writeable = yes
    path = /share/public
    guest ok = yes

[temp]
    browsable = yes
    valid users = root, @"share users"
    create mask = 0666
    directory mask = 0777
    writeable = yes
    path = /share/temp
    guest ok = no
```

However `guest ok = yes` does not seem to have any effect (temp is working as expected writable by root and users of the group). The user `nobody` which should be mapped to has the rwx right's for share folder.

So what is also needed to grant guest access to a specific share when security generally is `ads`?

Comment: i add always to the share that guest ok

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Security `ads` was not the problem - it just indicates that the samba-daemon accepts Kerberos-Tickets as authentication.

The real problem was `restrict anonymous = 2`. This disallows every anonymous connection to the server. Lowering the value to `1` allows to access a share anonymously by entering the path, `0` allows to even browse the share. Setting `0` oder `1` still checks access and may require additional authentication.

Source: https://www.samba.org/samba/docs/current/man-html/smb.conf.5.html#RESTRICTANONYMOUS